# How to calculate time complexity for below function?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

What is the time complexity for the below function?

```
void function(int n){
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++){. //n times
            for(int j=i ; j< i*i; j++){ // n*n times
                if(j%i == 0){
                    for(int k=0; k<j; k++){ // j times = n * n times.
                        ++counter;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Book says `O(n^5)`. But I couldn't understand why book didn't take `j%i` into account. The `k` loop determines based on that.  Can you clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider the part of code in which u have doubt :

```
for(int j=i ; j< i*i; j++)
{ 
  if(j%i == 0)
        {
               for(int p=0; p<j; p++){ 
               ++counter;
        }
      }
```

Let's just analyse this part of code . 
For every `i`, `j%i==0` will be true whenever `j` is a multiple of `i`, i.e.

```
 i, 2i, 3i, .... i*i // upto i*i only,since j<i*i
```

Now, for every `j`, Inside complexity is `O(j)`.

So Complexity for this part of code is :

[image]

So, Overall Complexity = `O(n*n^3)` = `O(n^4)`

Comment: Thank you. Are you suggesting all 3 loops will take O(n^4). I'm confused little bit. Can you please explain above with outer loop as well.

Comment: @Manoj I am writing another answer to make things clear. Will take a couple of minutes

Comment: @Manoj : Yeah for one particular i, inside loops(the part of code which I have mentioned) complexity is O(i^3), and since i will vary from 0-n, complexity equals O(n^4). Atleast that's what I am getting. Can u pls mention the book ?

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01N32J05C/ref=dp-kindle-redirect?_encoding=UTF8&btkr=1

Comment: Chapter 1, problem -57

Answer (score 1):

In fact the function runs in time O(n^4), since the `if` condition happens only once every approximately n loops. See below for precise analysis.

```
void function (int n) {
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        // Runs a total of n times
        for(int j=i; j< i*i; j++) {
            // Runs a total of (n^3 - n)/3 = O(n^3) times
            if(j%i == 0) {
                // Runs a total of (n^2 - n)/2 = O(n^2) times
                for(int k=0; k<j; k++) {
                    // Runs a total of (3n^4 - 10n^3 + 9n^2 - 2n)/24 = O(n^4) times
                    ++counter;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, How did you calculate the equation.? I ran for n = 5. But (n^3 - n)/3 is not coming.

Comment: @Manoj You can use a variant of Faulhaber's formula to get the exact expression, I believe. I used PARI/GP's `sumformal` command. The big-O expressions are easier but the exact expressions show that what I have is tight.